# Как запрограммировать на c# решение задачи целочисленного программирования?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, математика

Есть матрица элементов (строки - тип элемента, столбцы - разновидность типа в строке), значение элементов может быть от 0 до 10 (типа рейтинг элементов, 0 - нет элемента). 
Есть логические ограничения (например: элементы [1,2] и [2,3] не могут одновременно находится в решении), их количество может меняться. С помощью ограничений выбирается решение в виде определенного набора элементов, причем количество этих элементов не должно превышать определенного значения, которое задает пользователь перед решением задачи.

Необходимо решить данную задачу на С#, можно использовать сторонние бесплатные библиотеки.
Использую Visual Studio 2013.

Основная проблема - это как проверять логические ограничения, когда они могут изменятся, в ходе работы программы.

В данный момент решается эта задача с помощью ILOG OPL Studio 3.5. Данная студия морально устарела, а что либо новое купить нет возможности.

Пример ограничений в ILOG:

// в конечный результат обязательно должен входить один из видов деталей

Y[1,1]+Y[1,2]+Y[1,3]+Y[1,4]+Y[1,5]+Y[1,6]=1;

//первая деталь не сочетается со второй

Y[3,1]-Y[4,1]=0;

Comment: > В данный момент решается эта задача с помощью ILOG OPL Studio 3.5. Данная студия морально устарела, а что либо новое купить нет возможности.

Воспользуйтесь Visual Studio Express.

А сама задача не очень ясна. Может, приведете маленький пример с решением?

Comment: Если кратко, то так: Есть набор различных деталей(например множество разных процессоров, видеокарт, мат. плат и еще чего нибудь). В качестве ограничений будет несовместимость различных процессоров, видеокарт с мат платами опред. вида. В начале решения задачи ставится ограничения на количество деталей, например не больше пяти и ставится рейтинг деталей(чем выше значений, тем больше шанс, что оно будет включено в результат решения). При решении нужно пройти все ограничения и выбрать наиболее подходящий набор деталей.

Comment: Ну, а в чём конкретно проблема? Проблемы с алгоритмом (тут мы вам не поможем) или с имплементацией (тогда скажите, что конкретно не выходит)?

Comment: @VladD: "Основная проблема, это как проверять логические ограничения, когда они могут изменятся, в ходе работы программы."

Т.е. если бы ограничения не изменялись, то проблем нет, просто записать их все подряд и пропускать через них массив. А вот так как в ходе работы программы они могут добавляться, то тут я не знаю, как поступить. Нельзя же добавить в код ограничения после компиляции. Мне бы какой-то массив создать с ограничениями, который может обновляться в ходе работы программы и каждый элемент которого возвращал бы результат (подходят ли элементы или нет).

Comment: Код -- нельзя. Данные -- можно.

Comment: @alexlz: Угу, сам знаю. Но, какой тип данных использовать, я не знаю.